# Angular Move up/down through Dropdown List Items with Keyboard from Toggle Dropdown Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working to add keyboard functionality to my Dropdown List, below is the directive template. I am passing in data through isolate scope bound to "ctrl". I am using Angular and Bootstrap. I'm wondering if anybody out there knows a good solution for efficiently allowing a user to move up and down through the list. I think I am getting stuck mostly on having to have the angular "ng-keydown" directive on the button, and then moving from there and being able to focus an item with the up/down keys. And then being able to select a list item with the space bar.

```
<div class="dropdown select-container" ng-class="{'open' : ctrl.isOpen}">
  <div class="form-group" ng-if="ctrl.filterMode === 'off'">
    <button class="btn btn-default form-control" type="button" ng-keydown="ctrl.onButtonKeydown($event)" ng-click="ctrl.toggleDropdown($event)" ng-disabled="ctrl.ngDisabled === true">
        {{ctrl.selectedRow[ctrl.propertyName] ? ctrl.selectedRow[ctrl.propertyName] : ctrl.selectLabel}}
        <div class="pull-right"><i ng-class="{'fa fa-angle-up': ctrl.isOpen, 'fa fa-angle-down': !ctrl.isOpen}"></i></div>
    </button>
   </div>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu list-group" ng-disabled="ctrl.ngDisabled === true">
     <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="row in ctrl.rows | filter: ctrl.filterText" ng-class="{'active': row === ctrl.selectedRow, 'disabledStandardList': ctrl.ngDisabled}"
    ng-click="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row)">
       {{row[ctrl.propertyName]}}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item text-center" ng-show="ctrl.rows.length <= 0 || (ctrl.rows | filter: ctrl.filterText).length <= 0">
        {{ctrl.emptyMessage}}
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not able to get any keydown event unless the directive is on the button because the dropdown is hidden until the user clicks on the button to open it. Once the Dropdown list is open I want the user to be able to move up and down and highlight the current row as he or she is moving, as well as be able to select a row. Is it possible to use the css :focus class to add the list as the user moves up and down?

I have a somewhat working JQuery example but I feel like its hacked together and  I'm trying to avoid JQuery as much as possible and use Angular/Vanilla Javascript. If you have a solution that uses some jquery though please share! I've seen some other similar examples around but nothing that has helped me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you make a simple [plunk](https://plnkr.co) on this one?

Comment: Hey Minato, thanks for the time. For a visual its basically a Bootstrap Navigation Dropdown but I'm trying to add the ability for the user to use the up/down arrows to navigate the list and select a row with the space bar once the dropdown has been clicked open. But I can put up a plunker quick a little bit later.